# Sub Sum on a Collection in C#

Tags: c#

I have a collection of items in C# with two properties: productName and Volume. I want to perform a subsum on this collection by productname to get Volumes. In SQL it would look like this:

```
SELECT 
    productName, sum(Volume)
FROM collection
GROUP BY productName
```

I have tried to use LINQ, but it gives me the error that Data does not have GroupBy:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace PieChartDataTable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<DataItem> sortedPieData = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>(); //creates the pie data for reference later
        Data pieData = new Data();

        public class DataItem : IComparable
        {
            public string productName { get; set; }
            public double VOLUME { get; set; }
            public static DataItem createDataItem(string productName, double VOLUME)
            {
                DataItem dataItem = new DataItem();
                dataItem.productName = productName;
                dataItem.VOLUME = VOLUME;
                return dataItem;
            }
            public int CompareTo(object obj)
            {
                DataItem dataItem = obj as DataItem;
                if (dataItem == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a DataItem.");
                }
                return this.VOLUME.CompareTo(dataItem.VOLUME);
            }
        }

        public class Data : ObservableCollection<DataItem>
        {

            public Data()
            {
                Add(new DataItem { productName = "productName 1", VOLUME = 5 });
                Add(new DataItem { productName = "productName 2", VOLUME = 6 });
                Add(new DataItem { productName = "productName 3", VOLUME = 3 });
                Add(new DataItem { productName = "productName 3", VOLUME = 3 });
                Add(new DataItem { productName = "productName 3", VOLUME = 3 });
                //Add(new DataItem { productName = "productName 4", VOLUME = 7 });
                //Add(new DataItem { productName = "productName 5", VOLUME = 5 });
            }


            public ObservableCollection<DataItem> sortCollection()
            {
                ObservableCollection<DataItem> objSort = new
                    ObservableCollection<DataItem>(this.OrderBy(DataItem =>
                        DataItem.VOLUME));
                return objSort;
            }
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
            var result = Data.GroupBy(item => DataItem.productName)
             .Select(group =>
                    new DataItem
                    {
                        productName = group.Key,
                        VOLUME = group.Sum(item => DataItem.VOLUME)
                    })
             .ToList();
        }

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            sortedPieData = pieData.sortCollection();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your code to your question

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Aggregate-Operators-c51b3869

Comment: Add your C# code, or sample code representing your two collections.  Also add how you tried to calculate this, or if you are stuck at that point...

Comment: @ConradFrix does LINQ work for collections as well as lists?

Comment: @Sean `List`s are collections.  They inherit from `ICollection`.  Also, `GroupBy` is an extension to `IEnumerable`, which `ICollection` inherits.

Comment: @Lunyx I get that, but my data collection is not inheriting any LINQ methods.

Comment: @Sean LINQ methods are extension methods.  As long as your collection implements IEnumerable, they will be available automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your class looks like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public string productName { get; set; }
    public int Volume { get; set; }
}
```

You need to do something like this:

```
var result = input
             .GroupBy(item => item.productName)
             .Select(group =>
                    new Item
                    {
                        productName = group.Key,
                        Volume= group.Sum(item => item.Volume)
                    })
             .ToList();
```

Comment: Does this work for an ObservableCollection or just a simple List?

Comment: It works for any class that implements `IEnumerable<T>`, which includes `ObservableCollection<T>`

Comment: I have tried this, but it does not work. Please see me edited question above.

Comment: Do you need to store the results in the same `pieData` variable?

Comment: Ah I didn't call the pieData instance. Thanks. But now it doesn't like that DataItem is not a static class.

Comment: Now the line reads:

            var result = pieData.GroupBy(item => DataItem.productName)
             .Select(group =>
                    new DataItem
                    {
                        productName = group.Key,
                        VOLUME = group.Sum(item => DataItem.VOLUME)
                    })
             .ToList();

Comment: You should have `item => item.productName` instead of `item => DataItem.productName`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100184/discussion-between-sean-and-yacoub-massad).

Answer (score 1):

You need an instance of the class

```
            Data data = new Data();
            var result = data.GroupBy(item => item.productName)
             .Select(group =>
                    new DataItem
                    {
                        productName = group.Key,
                        VOLUME = group.Sum(item => item.VOLUME)
                    })
             .ToList();​
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't understand the syntax!